# buenas palabras x palabras buenas - ¿Tienen diferentes significados?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Encontré una frase en un libro que decía:

> No todas las buenas palabras son palabras buenas.

Investigué este tema y terminé encontrando el uso de ambas formas y aparentemente con el mismo significado, aunque el uso de "buenas palabras" parece ser más común que "palabras buenas". Pero me gustaría intentar comprenderlo mejor. En las dos oraciones siguientes, ¿hay alguna diferencia entre el uso de las dos formas? ¿Está permitido usar una o otra?

> No olvides que te amo y que todo lo que tengo para ti son **buenas
> palabras**.
> vs.
> No olvides que te amo y que todo lo que tengo para ti son **palabras
> buenas**.

y

> Confieso que estaba un poco preocupado, pero todo lo que escuché
> fueron **buenas palabras**.
> vs.
> Confieso que estaba un poco preocupado, pero todo lo que escuché
> fueron **palabras buenas**.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the DLE

[buenas palabras](https://dle.rae.es/palabra?m=form)

1. f. pl. Expresiones o promesas corteses, dichas con intención de agradar y convencer. Al final, todo se quedó en buenas palabras.

So it has a special significance whereas *palabras buenas* are just good words.

Comment: I think you meant "palabras buenas" in the last line, so I edited it. Feel free to roll back if I was mistaken.

Comment: @wimi serious brain fade there. I must proof read things more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Más allá de los casos de las frases hechas (como lo es *buenas palabras*), existen contados casos en que la posición del adjetivo modifica el significado. Concretamente, a menudo cuando se usa el adjetivo *buen(o)* antes del sustantivo, connota un sentido de repleción o suficiencia más allá del plano significado de ‘de calidad moral’: así, «Un **buen** día me harté» no quiere decir lo mismo que «Un día **bueno** me harté». Otro ejemplo es *pobre* (antepuesto a un sustantivo significa ‘que inspira pena’ y pospuesto, ‘sin dinero’). Más ejemplos [aquí](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/adjetivos/posicion#a-cambio-de-significado).

Comment: Muy buenas explicaciones. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.